# Is there a way to initialize multiple variables from array or List in Scala?

Tags: scala

What I want to do is basically the following in Java code:

```
String[] tempStrs = generateStrings();
final int hour = Integer.parseInt(tempStrs[0]);
final int minute = Integer.parseInt(tempStrs[1]);
final int second = Integer.parseInt(tempStrs[2]);
```

However, `tempStrs` is just a temporary variable, which is not used anymore. Then, this can be expressed in the following code in F#:

```
let [| hour; minute; second |] = Array.map (fun x -> Int32.Parse(x)) (generateStrings())
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Scala?
I know this can be done in Scala by

```
val tempInts = generateStrings().map(_.toInt)
val hour = tempInts(0)
val minute = tempInts(1)
val second = tempInts(2)
```

But is there a shorter way like F# (without temp variable)?

---

**Edit:**

I used

```
var Array(hour, minute, second) = generateStrings().map(_.toInt)
```

Of course, using `val` instead of `var` also worked.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> val numbers = List(1, 2, 3)
numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val List(hours, minutes, seconds) = numbers
hours: Int = 1
minutes: Int = 2
seconds: Int = 3
```

Comment: nice, but it seems to produce matcherror if the list doesn't have size 3.

Comment: @SebastienLorber `val List(hours, minutes, seconds, _*)`

Comment: @om-nom-nom that's right but it only works when size > 3 no? I think it works fine but can be dangerous to use in some situations

Comment: @SebastienLorber no it should be fine in case of 3 values: `val List(hours, minutes, seconds, _*) = List(1,2,3)` will compile and execute effortlessly. It will only fail in case of *less than 3* which is pretty desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

To deal with three or more values, you could use:

```
scala> val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val num1 :: num2 :: num3 :: theRest = numbers
num1: Int = 1
num2: Int = 2
num3: Int = 3
theRest: List[Int] = List(4)
```

For a size-3 list `theRest` will simply be the empty list. Of course, it doesn't handle lists of two or fewer elements.